# ES 6 compund statements holder

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am not sure if this is already possible in ES5, if not is there any change in ES6; is there any way to assign compound statements to a **thing**?

That would help it can be used anywhere that JavaScript expects a single statement.

like:

```
var leftValue = {
    x = Math.PI;
    cx = Math.cos(x);
    alert("cos(" + x + ") = " + cx);
}
//it wouldn't work
```

Comment: What is the expected result for `leftvalue`?

Comment: What do you mean by "compound statements"?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for a block with `let` variables or an IEFE.

Comment: I think what you want are "do expressions", which is currently a [stage 0 proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:do_expressions)

Comment: Are you looking for macros?

Comment: Felix, yes i was aiming that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can define compound statements in js, but they can't return a value, so you can't assign them to a variable or pass them like a function.

The only use-cases for them are the possibility to break them like a loop (or similar to `return;` in a function) or since ES6 to scope variables to this block.

```
leftValue: {
    let x = Math.random();  //block scope
    var cx = Math.cos(x*Math.PI);  //function scope
    if(x < .5) break leftValue;
    console.log('inside', x, cx);
}

try {
    console.log('outside', x , cx);
}catch(err){
    console.log('catched', err, cx);
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, but I don't think it actually answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but I think I do. Do you mean a way to group those statements so that you can execute them in order without repeating them every time? That's just a function.

```
var leftValue = function ( ) {
    var x = Math.PI;
    var cx = Math.cos(x);
    alert("cos(" + x + ") = " + cx);
};

// Execute those three statements
leftValue();
// Execute them all again
leftValue();
```

Comment: Why is `cx` a `var` but `x` is not?

Comment: So yes, functions were already possible in ES5, if you're asking for the obvious :-)